# For which values of s is the function continuous?

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces

[image]

since **x** is a vector **x*x** becomes $x^2+y^2$. And then what $s$ value should I put?

Answer (score 3):

$f$ is clearly continuous at any point $(x,y) \neq(0,0)$. In order to examine the origin use polar coordinates $x=r \cos \theta,y=r \sin \theta$. The function is then $f=r^{s-2} (\cos \theta+ \sin \theta)^s$ (for $r=0$ it is zero). you want that near the origin (i.e. as $r \to 0$) the value of $f$ will approach zero. How large must $s$ be?

Comment: so as r approaches 0, f will approach 0.
Then s is 2? or is s 3?

Comment: Not quite, $s$ must be strictly greater than 2. If $s=2$ then $f=(\cos \theta+ \sin \theta)^2$ which doesn't go to zero as $r \to 0$

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael. really appreciate it